# Where to find user installed certificate android 4.0 and up

Tags: android, security, certificate, ssl-certificate

I've installed my certificate (.crt) as follows:
connected the device to my computer --> copied the certificate to internal storage --> on device went to settings->security->install from storage --> and got "installed successfully" or something (it asked me to put a pin code for the device).

Then I've tried looking it up in Settings->security->trusted credentials and couldn't find it in System nor User tabs... (I've understood it should be in User tab, but it's empty).

I think there's no problem in the installation process because it asked me to put pin code (and didn't let me undo it until I've removed all certificates by clicking "clear credentials" from security menu)

Help some1?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, still haven't found any answer.. any1?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the exact same problem. My device said: "XYZ certificate installed" but can't seem to find a way to see it "installed" in the system.

Comment: If it's of any help, you can confirm that it's installed by looking under /data/misc/keystore

Very helpful article here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.ca/2011/11/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html?q=self-signed

Comment: It appears to me that Android only accepts self signed CA (ssCA). Not self signed certificate (SSC). This link proposed that create a ssCA to sign the SSC and import them both. (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61540/self-signed-certificate-install-claims-success-but-android-acts-as-if-cert-isn)

Answer (score 11):

Had this same problem as well. Make sure that the certificate that you are installing is actually a CA certificate and not just a simple x509 certificate. Unfortunately the certificate installer that comes with ICS will gladly install the certificate even if it's not a CA certificate. It will misleadingly say that the certificate was successfully installed. It will even put the file under /data/misc/keystore. However, it provides no feedback to the user that it can't really use that certificate for the intended purpose.

For development/testing, here is a handy guide on how to create this self-signed CA certificate: http://langui.sh/2009/01/18/openssl-self-signed-ca/

Answer (score 1):

After all the steps (put the file under /data/misc/keystore and making sure the certificate is a CA), restart your device, the cert should show up.

Answer (score 1):

Since API 24 (Android 7.0) you have check it in

***Setting-->Security-->User Credentials***

where you can list all of users certificates. **Below API 24** there is no option in settings to show user certificates (PKCS12 with private key). The easiest option that I checked on **API 19 21 22 23** is install certificate and after finish go to server that required **two-way SSL** authentication using **Google Chrome** application. Google Chrome should show you list of installed certificates. In case of using Virtual Device without Google Chrome you can download it from **[this site](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/variant-%7B%22arches_slug%22%3A%5B%22x86%22%5D%7D/)**. After downloading drag and drop application on virtual device's screen.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073479/3739540) was a great tip, but some things in the linked post were out of date due to changes in what Chrome accepts as a proper certificate (subject alt name, digest algorithm)

Here it is in full as of today:
If you have a proper CA certificate, it will say "includes: ... 1 CA", if it just says one certificate, it will install but not act as a CA.

Firstly, Create myca.conf

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = myca

[ crl_ext ]
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy  #this would copy the issuer name to altname
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ myca ]
new_certs_dir = /tmp
unique_subject = no
certificate = root.cer
database = certindex
private_key = privkey.pem
serial = serialfile
default_days = 365
default_md = sha1
policy = myca_policy
x509_extensions = myca_extensions

[ myca_policy ]
commonName = supplied
stateOrProvinceName = supplied
countryName = supplied
emailAddress = optional
organizationName = supplied
organizationalUnitName = optional

[ myca_extensions ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always
keyUsage = digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://mp-test.com.au/myca.crl

subjectAltName = @alt_names
```

Run these commands the first time only:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -x509 -nodes -out root.cer
openssl pkcs12 -export -out root.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in root.cer
cp privkey.pem root.pem
touch certindex
echo 01 > serialfile
```

Now run these for each domain:

```
domain=www.example.org
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -x509 -nodes -out root.cer
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out ${domain}.csr -keyout ${domain}.key
cat myca.conf > temp.conf
printf "[alt_names]\nDNS.1=${domain}\n" >> temp.conf
openssl ca -md sha512 -batch -config temp.conf -notext -in ${domain}.csr -out ${domain}.cer
openssl x509 -noout -text -in ${domain}.cer
openssl pkcs12 -export -out root.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in root.cer
```

root.pfx is your CA certificate that can be installed on device.
${domain.cer} is your website certificate that should be trusted once root.pfx is installed.